# Qual é o limite de tamanho da tecnologia IndexedDB?

Tags: html, html5, banco-de-dados, indexeddb

Hoje no trabalho mencionaram a tecnologia `IndexedDB` para solucionar um problema aqui na empresa, mas entretando surgiram-me diversas dúvidas, sendo uma delas:

**Qual é o limite de dados que se pode armazenar em uma IndexedDB?**

---

*Ainda relacionadas como a dimensão da BD:*

> - Existe um limite diferenciado entre navegadores?
> - É necessário permissões para utilizar a mesma tal como outras tecnologias?(ex: API de notificações )
> - É possível guardar ficheiros, imagens, músicas, etc...?
> - A base de dados é persistente? Permanece após fechar a janela do navegador? Se sim, não corre o risco de ser considerada como ficheiro temporário sendo eliminada por softwares externos posteriormente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Existe um limite diferenciado entre navegadores?

Isso é detalhe de implementação e muda em cada navegador, onde está rodando e até da época. Não trabalhe com isso. Hoje é comum limitar em 6% do armazenamento total disponível. Em geral a sua aplicação pode usar apenas 20% disso, mas lembre-se que isso não vale igual em todos casos.

> É necessário permissões para utilizar a mesma tal como outras tecnologias? Ex: API de notificações

Sim, claro, qualquer recurso da máquina precisa de autorização. Pode ter que pedir mais espaço, não precisa ser dado espaço de uma vez só. Mas é possível em alguns casos pedir acesso ilimitado. Lembre-se, depende.

> É possível guardar ficheiros, imagens, músicas, etc.?

Em tese sim, mas ele não foi criado para isso, não o trate como um banco de dados completo.

> A base de dados é persistente? Permanece após fechar a janela do navegador? Se sim, não corre o risco de ser considerada como ficheiro temporário sendo eliminada por softwares externos posteriormente?

De forma geral é possível, mas é detalhe de implementação, m porém não é algo que você tenha muito controle, pode ser alterado por outras formas, apagado, enfim, não trate como um banco de dados. Ele não é temporário, mas não é algo que você deva confiar. O padrão é ser temporário.

Lembre-se que desenvolver para web, ao contrário do que as pessoas pensam, não é fazer uma vez e roda em qualquer lugar. Cada navegador é uma plataforma diferente, inclusive é diferente dependendo da plataforma que ele está rodando. Se você precisa desse controle todo, não deve usar web, precisa de um aplicativo nativo. Use a ferramenta certa.

[image: Carro com cavalo dentro]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Concordo consigo plenamente, comecei hoje a explorar a IndexedDB para avaliar a necessidade/vantagem em aplica-la em problemas futuros e achei interessante partilhar no SOPT algumas "dúvidas". Fico a aguardar novas respostas. BTW Adorei a imagem do fim, resume bem a sua resposta huauau.